# How do I store and update an array using hooks immediately after the component is loaded?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I am using functional components and hooks. Once the component is rendered for the first time, in the `useEffect` function, I have a loop to get unique categories from a list of products.

Once these categories are extracted, I store them in an array in the state of the component with `setCategoriesState`. However, as it stands, the state doesn't reflect the updated list of categories unless the component is re-rendered. Is there a better way to do this?

```
const [categoriesState, setCategoriesState] = useState([])
var categories = []

useEffect(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < props.products.items.length; i++) {
    if (categories.indexOf(props.products.items[i].category) === -1) {
      categories = [...categories, props.products.items[i].category]
    }
  }

  setCategoriesState(categories)

}, [])
```

This is how I'm using the categoriesState

```
{categoriesState.map((cat) => <Text >{cat}</Text>)}
```

Comment: you are using it in ```react-native``` or ```reactjs``` because you added both as your tag.

Comment: I'm using React Native

Comment: but you are updating your state with `setCategoriesState` this mean your component will re-render!!

Comment: how are you using `categoriesState`?

Comment: @WillJenkins `{categoriesState.map((cat) => <Text >{cat}</Text>)}`

Answer (score 1):

You should include your `categories` declaration inside the `useEffect`, and spread your `categoriesState`

```
const [categoriesState, setCategoriesState] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  let categories = [...categoriesState]

  for (let i = 0; i < props.products.items.length; i++) {
    if (categories.indexOf(props.products.items[i].category) === -1) {
      categories = [...categories, props.products.items[i].category]
    }
  }

  setCategoriesState(categories)

}, [])
```

Comment: This looks like a good idea. There's a note in the documentation on `useEffect` that might be helpful to understand why the state of your categories does not update: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Comment: Looking into it.